# Store rarely changed data but frequently accessed, which is solution?

Tags: .net, database, oracle, database-design

My Oracle database contains some simple, rarely-changed data (it takes about months or even years for it to change). But it's frequently accessed (hundred times/day). I think to continuously access it in database is expensive.

EDIT: I'm thinking about an alternative way to store this data, not in database, for example, store it in my app's cache, but I'm really confused about data consistency.
How can I do this efficiently?

EDIT: my original question is quite too general. I want to explain it clearer:

I have a table that contains:

```
MinValue       MaxValue       PackageID
1                4             1
5                10            2
11               50            3
```

When the client send an request to our service, it will send the amount, then our service has to determine which package this request belong to. This depends on the amount, and may be changed due to business needs (as I mentioned before, it's very rarely changed).

I use this query to do this:

```
select packageid from vmeet_temp where amount between minvalue and maxvalue
```

Yes, it does work. But since I'm an inexperienced programmer, I doubt that if there's more efficient way to archive this.

So my question is: for our need, should we store this information in database, or not? If not, which solution to go?

Comment: what is the server written with?

Comment: About how many rows in that table?  A hundred? A million?

Comment: it does not seem to reach a hundred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a table, and let the DBMS worry about it.  It has caching and is good at making sure that frequently used data is stored in memory so it does not need to go to disk for it.  If you really want to, you can load the data into your application - you run the (small) risk that the data will be stale.  But generally, let the DBMS worry about it and it will get it right for you.

If the table is only 10 rows, and the rows are modest in size (up to a few hundred bytes each), then the DBMS will probably not bother with using an index even if you create one - it knows that it will be simpler and more efficient to use the table directly.  Even simple-minded optimizers manage that.  Obviously, if you bludgeon it into using the index with misplaced hints, then you get to pay the performance penalty.  If left to its own devices, it is unlikely the optimizer would use the index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I explained wrongly. I think that query to database is expensive for a simple data, so I'm thinking about cache this data in my app. Can you please give me any suggestion?

Comment: @Vimvq1987: it depends what you're going to do with the values, how big they are, and how you're going to have your app determine which is the appropriate value to look at now.  I said you can load (cache) the values in your application; but if you have to post process the result row of a query to sort out which of the ten values needs to be passed on for further processing, it may just be simpler (and not much slower) to ignore the caching in the app and let the DBMS do its stuff - return you the data you need.  OTOH, if you've measured the overhead and caching will help - use caching.

Comment: @Vimvq1987: if data consistency is a concern, let the DBMS handle it. Oracle has spent many man-years getting it right, so you don't have to worry about it. Prove that there really is a performance problem, and prove that your solution really could fix it.  You are in danger of indulging in [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization), which is the 'root of all evil'. If you don't know the cost (for example, you haven't run the queries without the small table being mentioned and seen a dramatic improvement performance) then you are indulging.

Comment: @Vimvq1987: Remember the laws of optimization: (1) Don't optimize.  (2) _(For experts only)_ Don't optimize yet.

Comment: @Vimvq -- Oracle has a super optimised chache. It does a lot more than simply hold data in a buffer, queries and results of queries are also cached if it thinks its a good idea. The only extra overhead that occurs using oracle is the fairly trivial matching of your sql to its sql cache and the overhead in your code to access the columns. Other than hard coding the data in your program I doubt you will find anything faster.

Comment: I just added more details. Please check it and help me on this more-specific situation :)

Answer (score 2):

To start, @Jonathan Leffler is correct, databases are really good at caching simple queries over limited data. So if the database server is not exhibiting signs of stress, such as high CPU utilization or disk I/O things are probably fine. Then if it is, Oracle has [management views](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/jstrode/www/oraview/index.html) to tell you what queries are consuming the most processing power.

Regarding caching, if you only have one server and the underlying table is updated through the same application you can use a write through strategy. If a multi-server setup, you'll need messaging to refresh the cache on each server. If the data is not updated through the application, a write behind strategy is necessary to check or know when data changes and refresh the cache.

If performance is your real concern, I would suggest focusing on load testing instead to identify bottlenecks using a tool such as JMeter. Stress with iteratively more threads recording performance metric(s) each time - typically page response time - and chart it out in Excel. If you see a exponential line you've identified a bottleneck. Back off some and start adding counters in code to see where the slow down is. You may find it has nothing to do with the data you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the Client Result Cache in 11g.

An example is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-jul/o48odpnet-098170.html)

["This feature enables client-side caching of SQL query result sets in memory. The
client result cache is completely transparent to ODP.NET applications, and its
cache of result set data is automatically kept consistent with any session or database
server side changes that would alter the results.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/odp-1-131954.pdf)

[.NET applications calling the same query multiple times see improved performance
since query results are retrieved locally. Local client processing is faster than
making database round trips to re-execute a query and fetch results. If applications
are frequently running the same queries, they will experience a significant
performance improvement when their results are cached on the client, as well as a
reduction in database server load."](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/odp-1-131954.pdf)

Comment: I just added more details. Please check it and help me on this more-specific situation :)

Answer (score 1):

Even with little db data, caching is a good idea.  It is meant for this type of scenario -- rarely updated data.  It can really speed things up, because you don't even need to go to the DB in  a lot of cases.

Here is an article that describes caching in .NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

If your app is slow, you need to get in there with a profiler and figure out where the bottleneck is...

Comment: I updated my question, I'm using Oracle. The data is very simple, it's about ten rows, and I don't think an index is needed

Comment: @vimvq1987, whats the server written in?

Answer (score 0):

Any query hitting a small table is unlikely to be expensive relative the the other data access a typical system will perform.

Optimising this query via cacheing is likely to require considerable effort (as the other answers show).

As an inexperienced programmer you might want to familiarse your self with the following quote:

> premature optimization is the root of
>   all evil